# in react hook how can I empty my states and show the empty inputs in same time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

in react hook how can I empty my states and show the empty inputs in same time?
My problem is, when I reset state my Input remain full.

```
    const [state, setState] = useState([initial])

     handleInputChange(event) {
        setState({
       event.target.value
        });
      }
    const resetState = () => {  
        setState([initial])
        }
export default function newState () {

return(
    <input onChange={handleInputChange()} />
    <button onClick={resetState}/>
)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying your code but what do you mean "empty" your states? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: `setState` is used in classical component, please format your code which may be good for others to help

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish from this code, as it's invalid. There are two types of components: functions, and classes. It seems you're mixing concepts from both, perhaps copying from a mix of tutorials? I see there are already some good answers trying to clear up the confusion, but in general I would recommend reading React's excellent documentation on the matter. https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 0):

What (I think) you mean to to is this:

```
export default function Foo({ initial }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(initial)

  return(
    <>
      <input onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)} value={value} />
      <button onClick={() => setValue(initial)}>Reset</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

You have to call `useState` inside your components.

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:** You have initialized `state` to an array, reset it to an array, but update it to an object.

Always keep your data types consistent, in this case neither seem appropriate. I would suggest just using a string value.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(initial)

handleInputChange(event) {
  setState(event.target.value);
}

const resetState = () => {  
  setState(initial)
}
```

Remember - The `useState` updater is not the same as the class based `setState`. `setState` *merges* the previous and new state values. `useState` *replaces*. So if your state is not an object the update call `setState({ newState })` is not correct anymore.

**Second problem:** `<input onChange={handleInputChange()} />` is not right. What this code does is assign `onChange` the value returned from calling `handleInputChange`. What you actually want is to assign `onChange` the function itself.

```js
// no ()
<input onChange={handleInputChange} />
```

**Third Problem:** Your state hook doesn't appear to be inside the functional component and it doesn't look like its set up for use as a custom hook (I could be wrong). Move them into the component function.